# Curl causes apache to seg fault

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, apache2, php-5.3

I'm a bit stuck, curl causes segmentation faults in apache and I can't find out why.

I made a simple case, trying to understand :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://google.fr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_exec($ch);
```

My conf, apache2, php5.3, ubuntu 11.10. Tried to reinstall php5-curl with no success

If you have ever seen this before, and have an idea please tell me !

Comment: An old question I know, but this may help someone who ends up here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32383219/915762

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding curl_close($ch); as last line in your example?

Still, it shouldn't segfault ;)
Try running the code manually like this: php test.php

Comment: Adding curl_close didn't change anything.
I didn't think about trying it in cli, and it works ! This could mean that it's curl _with apache_ which causes seg fault...