# PHP + cURL: simple test script not working (on one machine)

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have the following a very simple PHP script that uses cURL to load a web page and to it display

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init("http://www.reddit.com/");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
  $content = "Hello, World!";
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  echo $content;
?>
```

On my local machine, it works perfectly well -- but not on my server machine. Here I get a "The connection was reset" error in Firefox. The line that causes trouble seems to be `$content = curl_exec($ch);`. If I comment this line, I get to see `Hello, World!` on both machines.

When calling `phpinfo()` on both machines, the `cURL` section looks pretty similar. What could be the problem here that it works on one machine but not on another. Basically, both run Ubuntu 14.04, with Apache 2 and PHP 5. What configurations or permissions might be different. I'm a bit at a loss where to look.

EDIT: As arkascha suggested, I've checked the Apache `error.log` file. And indeed, if I see the following error as soon as I execute the `curl_exec` command:

`[core:notice] [pid 28267] AH00051: child pid 28274 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

Comment: read this link  http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: @ManojKushwaha Would you mind to be _a little more precise?_ Could you please point out what in that page you refer to? So why that page is relevant here?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the http servers error log file...

Comment: you sure you want to use `$content` twice like this ? that makes no sense. check `curl_error` after execution. It might contain an error which you are looking for.

Comment: @Jigar do you guys even bother to _read_ the question? The OP explained that!

Comment: `If I comment this line, I get to see Hello, World! on both machines` isn't that obvious @arkascha

Comment: @Jigar "not that obvious"? What else would you prefer? It is absolutely precise since it clearly shows the way how the OP tries to assure that it is indeed that commented line that makes the difference.

Comment: @Christian which OS and PHP version ? do you have access to shell ?

Comment: @Jigar, these are the version numbers: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Apache 2.4.7, PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9, cURL 7.35.0. There are actually identical on both machines. I have full/sudo access to the shell.

Comment: not sure if this is related, check MPM of apache. is it prefork or workers. compare on both environment. `apache2 -V` in shell should give you the answer.

Comment: @Jigar: Admittedly, I have no idea what that means, but the output is on both machines the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before and solved with the solution [given here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/issues/261). On top of your file, add line below and test it again please.

```
<?php
ini_set('zend.enable_gc', 0);
....
....
```

Comment: No change, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through something similar. A CURL connection between two servers, worked most of the time, but would crash approximately one time in five.

When it crashed, Firefox would report that "the connection was reset" and Safari would tell me that "the server unexpectedly dropped the connection". The Apache error log would show `exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`.

Adding traces, I discovered it was actually the `curl_close` function which was causing the crash, not the `curl_exec` which was actually working fine (and the results of which were appearing in my logs).

Eventually, I pinpointed this line in my code...

`curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

...which I was using to output the raw data of the CURL session to a log file, for debugging purposes. Since I commented-out that line, the error stopped occurring.

So it seems that using CURLOPT_VERBOSE can cause CURL to crash, and take PHP/Apache with it. (I've also seen a discussion from a CPP programmer saying the same thing about CURL on CPP.)